# Import data - with firebase keys

Tags: arrays, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, import

I am trying to import some data into firebase

```
{
"people": 
  [
    {
       "name": "John Smith",
        "age": 23,
    },
    {
        "name": "Tony Jones",
        "age": 61,
    },
]
}
```

This is fine but it adds a "traditional" array index in firebase (0,1) - which I believe is bad?

When I insert a new value via my web form I get a mix

```
 "0" : {
     "name": "John Smith",
      "age": 23,
  },
 "1" : {
     "name": "Tony Jones",
      "age": 61,
  },
  "-LgWkhX2DdD_ChbWJkXo" : { // inserted via form it has a firebase index
     "name": "Simon Green", 
      "age": 37,
  }
```

How can I get the initial inserted data to use firebase indexes it is just a normal .json file.

```
{
    "people": 
    [
        {
          "name": "John Smith",
         "age": 23,
        },
  {
        "name": "Tony Jones",
        "age": 61,
    },

   ]
}
```

Comment: How do you "import" the data? Through the Firebase console?

Answer (score 0):

When you write array type JSON data into Realtime Database, you are going to get array type numeric indexes in the database.  If you don't want to write like this, you will have to convert the array yourself - there is no API that's going to do that for you.  You'll have to read the JSON, iterate each element of the array, and write each item into the database the way you want it to be written.  It looks like perhaps you want to add each item using an automatic push ID, since you are trying to create something that looks like "-LgWkhX2DdD_ChbWJkXo".